# Is it possible to run a Wordpress site on Google Cloud for free forever using "Always free products"?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, web-hosting

I am planning to create a wordpress website which won't need more than 3-4 GBs of storage since I'll only post textual content and not much media files. I am targeting to get around 10k pageviews per day at peak

https://cloud.google.com/free/

Google Cloud offers a 12 month free trial for its products, but some services are termed as "Always Free Products". Is it possible to substitute a paid wordpress hosting like Bluehost or Dreamhost by the free products that Google Cloud offers? The websites I have read don't provide a clear explanation of whether this is possible. (I can't use wordpress.com because I need to use my own theme and plugins)

If that's possible, why isn't it a mainstream choice for wordpress bloggers?

Answer (score 4):

If you use one micro server instance while installing your WordPress virtual machine; Google simply provides this micro server instance free forever.

Yes you can simply use Google cloud platform WordPress installation free forever but for that you have to follow some precautions.

1. Sign up for Google cloud platform
2. Install WordPress on on Google compute engine using Google Click to deploy
3. During Google click to deploy WordPress installation select 1 micro server instance
4. Select simple boot drive
5. Assign your project an external IP address
6. Create your DNS domain name servers in Google cloud platform
7. Add your Google cloud platform DNS in Domain registrars DNS settings
8. Add your newly installed WordPress installation external IP address in GCP DNS
9. Monitor your GCP account on regular basis for your free credit limit
10. Backup your website before your free trial ends.

Create a new Google cloud platform account with new banking details and repeat the process mentioned above.

[WordPress on Google Cloud Platform](https://networks.pk/host-wordpress-google-cloud-free-forever/)

Comment: I had a doubt today, and just to confirm: on the deployment page Google doesn't specify that it will be included in the Free Tier, but it is and you won't be charged if it's  in the limits

Answer (score 1):

Answer was a bit outdated, so revising: it's possible, but probably not the very best idea.

You can host WordPress, for free, on Google Cloud Platform. You can use [App Engine Standard, App Engine Flexible, Kubernetes Engine, Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/wordpress/).

The thing is, as far as I understand WordPress, you need an SQL database, and there's no free tier for [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/).

The cheapest you can go with Cloud SQL is around $10/month for a `db-f1-micro` managed instance with some storage. It's not covered by an SLA, and performance is likely not good enough for production, but it's managed.

If you want to cut costs, you can host your own MySQL on an always free `f1-micro` Compute Engine instance. You'll have to manage it yourself (security, upgrades, reboots, etc). If you go this route, choose any US region for App Engine Standard PHP, and an `f1-micro` Compute Engine instance with 30GB of persistent disk in the same region (performance scales with disk size, so go big). Host (mostly) static files on Cloud Storage to take the load off of your servers, and use a free CDN (like Cloudflare) to cache as much as you can.

The markup on MySQL Second Generation Cloud SQL instances is around 100% over the Compute Engine instance that host them (`db-n1-standard-1` is $49.31 *vs* `n1-standard-1` is $24.27).

Comment: there is a Cloud Datastore on https://cloud.google.com/free/ , which gives 1GB storage and 'Highly Scalable NoSQL Database'. does that work for the sql requirement?

Comment: It's NoSQL, so, no.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in deed, as long as you don't go over the limitations of Always free usage.

Kindly check the Always Free resources are available for the GCP services listed in the following table, subject to the listed limitations. Please check below link for reference:

https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free-usage-limits